# On deletion of a model, how to delete the child model's polymorphic model in laravel

Tags: database, laravel

Say I have 5 models, Model A, B, C, D, E. [image]

```
A migration 
    function up() {
        $table->increments('id');
    }


B migration 
    function up() {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('a_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('a_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('as')
              ->onDelete('cascade')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
    }

C migration 
    function up() {
        $table->increments('id')
        $table->integer('b_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('b_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('as')
              ->onDelete('cascade')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
    }
```

also c has polymorphic relations with D, E

on deleting a. b and c deletes due to cascading. but the related model e or f doesn't delete. how can i implement it.

Comment: The easy way is to add cascades to your D and E migrations.

Comment: @Jeffrey does cascading works in polymorphic relations

Answer (score 0):

You could override class `C` `delete` method and do logic there:

```
public function delete() {
   set e to Collection<E>;
   set d to Collection<D>;
   if parent::delete() is true
       remove e;
       remove d;

}
```